# Where is the bug in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm trying to create three dots of varying radii on a canvas, that do NOT touch or overlap each other. I'm using Jquery and Raphael for the circles. However when I run the program, they do sometimes overlap/touch, but I can't find the logic error in my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var canvasx = 1450;
    var canvasy = 743;
    var paper = Raphael(0, 0, canvasx, canvasy);
    var circles = new Array;
    var colorarray = new Array("black", "red", "blue");
    var circleoffsetx = canvasx / 4;
    var circleoffsety = canvasy / 4;
    var iterations = 3;
    var circleoverlap = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        var circlecolor = colorarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorarray.length)];
        var circlex = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvasx / 2) + circleoffsetx);
        var circley = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvasy / 2) + circleoffsety);
        var circleradius = Math.floor((Math.random() * 75) + 25);
        if (circles.length > 0) {
            for (var j = 0; j < circles.length; j++) {
                var allcirclex = circles[j[0]];
                var allcircley = circles[j[1]];
                var allcircleradius = circles[j[2]];
                var radiussum = circleradius + allcircleradius;
                if (Math.abs(circlex - allcirclex) <= radiussum || Math.abs(circley - allcircley) <= radiussum) {
                    iterations++;
                    circleoverlap = true;
                    console.log("OVERLAP");
                    break;

                }
            }
            if (circleoverlap === false) {
                circles.push(paper.circle(circlex, circley, circleradius).attr({"stroke": circlecolor, "stroke-width": 3}));
                circles[i] = [circlex, circley, circleradius];
                console.log("NO OVERLAP");
            }
        }
        if (circles.length < 1) {
            circles.push(paper.circle(circlex, circley, circleradius).attr({"stroke": circlecolor, "stroke-width": 3}));
            circles[i] = [circlex, circley, circleradius];
        }
        console.log(circles[0]);
    }
});
```

So I am creating a circle and saving it's x,y,radius in a two dimensional array (circles) and then trying to see if the new circle would touch/overlap the existing ones by seeing if the distance between the circle x,y is smaller or equal to the sum of the radii. But once again, it doesn't seem to work. I am also console.logging if they overlap or not (OVERLAP vs NO OVERLAP) and it always logs NO OVERLAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fixed script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var canvasW = 1450;
  var canvasH = 743;
  var paper = Raphael(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);

  var circles = new Array();
  var colorArray = new Array("black", "red", "blue");

  var circleOffsetX = canvasW / 4;
  var circleOffsetY = canvasH / 4;
  var iterations = 3;
  var circleOverlap;

  // keep creating circles until done
  while (circles.length < iterations) {
    var circleColor = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];
    var circleX = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvasW / 2) + circleOffsetX);
    var circleY = Math.floor((Math.random() * canvasH / 2) + circleOffsetY);
    var circleR = Math.floor((Math.random() * 75) + 25);
    circleOverlap = false; // assume new circle doesn't overlap existing ones
    // test against existing circles
    for (var j = 0; j < circles.length; j++) {
      var dx = circles[j].x - circleX;
      var dy = circles[j].y - circleY;
      if (Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) <= circleR + circles[j].r + 3) {
        circleOverlap = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    // no overlap? then add to array
    if (!circleOverlap) circles.push({ x: circleX, y: circleY, r: circleR, c: circleColor });
  }
  // create Raphael circles based on array data
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i] = paper.circle(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, circles[i].r).attr({
      "stroke": circles[i].c,
      "stroke-width": 3
    });
  }
});
```

I changed a few things, should be pretty self-explanatory though.

Comment: Man, you're solution makes so much more sense. How do can I learn to think like this? it

Comment: Don't worry, it took me a long time to get there :D All you need is practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for the distance between two points is very wrong.

If you have a point (X1, Y1) and a point (X2, Y2) the distance between them is sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2).  That's the value you need to compare against radius1 + radius2.

You're also not correctly reading any of the values from your circles array - you should be using `circles[j][0]` and not `circles[j[0]]` which is always going to return `undefined` because j is not an array and so j[0] is undefined.